# When writing a Twig Extension in Symfony, why must you provide a getName()?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Here is the Symfony Guide to writing Twig Extensions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Note it says to provide:

```
// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

Here is the Twig API: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1.x/lib/Twig/Extension.php

There is no getName function() there.

So why do we have to provide one? What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `Twig_ExtensionInterface`, which `Twig_Extension` implements, `getName()` need to be implemented in your custom twig extension according to the interface.

According to twig documentation by folks at sensiolabs ([link here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-an-extension)):

> To keep your extension class clean and lean, it can inherit from the built-in `Twig_Extension` class instead of implementing the whole interface. That way, you just need to implement the `getName()` method as the `Twig_Extension` provides empty implementations for all other methods.
>
> The `getName()` method must return a unique identifier for your extension.

Comment: Sidenote : The `getName()` method is also used by `Twig_Environment` to register and the retrieve the extension. see [getExtension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/master/Twig_Environment.html#method_getExtension)

Comment: As of `Twig 2.X` the (mandatory) function `getName()` was removed from the [interface](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#creating-extensions)

Answer (score 1):

Method `getName()` is defined in `Twig_ExtensionInterface` implemented by `Twig_Extension`.

Source here: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1.x/lib/Twig/ExtensionInterface.php

Its nice way to ensure every Extension will have name.

Answer (score 0):

Like @DarkBee mentioned in his comment, the `getName()` method of class `Twig_ExtensionInterface` has been removed in version 2.0 of Twig.

From [Twig 1.x API](https://twig.symfony.com/api/1.x/Twig_ExtensionInterface.html#method_getName) we can see that that the method has been deprecated since version 1.26 and removed in version 2.0. It can be seen also in the [changelog](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v2.4.4/CHANGELOG#L205):

> 1.26.0 (2016-10-02)
>
> - ...
> - deprecated `Twig_ExtensionInterface::getName()`

In addition, looking e.g. at the [`getExtension($name)` method in `Environment.php` of Twig version 1.25.0](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v1.25.0/lib/Twig/Environment.php#L783), we can see that the method is used to get an extension by its *name*, whereas in [version 1.26.0](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v1.26.0/lib/Twig/Environment.php#L805) and [version 2.4.4](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v2.4.4/lib/Twig/Environment.php#L630), the method is used to get an extension by its *class name*.

So,

- If you use Twig version 1.25 or earlier, you need to implement the `getName()` method.
- If you use Twig version 1.26.0 (released 2nd Oct 2016) or later, or version 2.x, you shouldn't implement the `getName()` method. (Well, you can, but it's not used by Twig.)